# php postgres fetch array conversion to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, database-table

Hi i've been working on a task of porting some code from some old postgresql driven site to a newer and imported site running against mysql.  There are some sections of code that use's function calls like:

```
$DataArrDT = pg_fetch_array($result,$i);
```

Then later on in the code there are sections like:

```
if ($DataArrDT[0]=="")
```

based on the index of the datatable array, different sections to tables are constructed for visibility.

However, when the code was modified to hand the mysql_fetch_array function call tons and tons of warnings are thrown.  I completely expected that; however, i've been working for quite some time attempting to resolve them, and i've reached my knowledge banks dead end.

here is what i attempted:

```
 $DataArrDT = mysql_fetch_array($result,$i);
```

or

```
$DataArrDT = mysql_fetch_assoc($result,$i);
```

regardless of the selection i still receive errors like:

*Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in .php on line xxx*

And those undefined offset warnings typically go hand-in-hand with

**Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() [function.mysql-fetch-assoc]:
The result type should be   either MYSQL_NUM, MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_BOTH in .php on line xxx**

If there is something i'm missing to help you provide feedback on how to resolve, please let me know and i'll add to the initial posts.  this is something i need to figure out. If there is a link i should read also post that so in the future i can expand my depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `pg_fetch_array()` and `mysql_fetch_array()` are not exactly the same. `pg_fetch_array()` receives three parameters, but `mysql_fetch_array()` only two. The parameter not supported by `mysql_fetch_array()` is precisely the one being used in your case. `$i`, as far as I can see, and according to the reference:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php

is used to indicate: *Row number in result to fetch*. That option is not available in the mysql version, check it out:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

I can't tell you right now about an alternative, as I'm not pretty sure what the code is intended to do.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I should have read the manual a little more closely.  I could accomplish what i needed by doing: mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH) or  MYSQL_NUM. that worked.  Thanks for forcing me to re-read :)